# How to identify cron entry in spring is applicable today?

Tags: spring-boot, cron

i have a list of cron entries in my database which has only values for date,day of month,day of week.

Sample cron values in my database.
"0 0 * * * *" 
"* * * 15 2 *" 
"* * * * * MON-FRI"

How i do check if there are any cron entry in my database that is applicable for today?i have to use this in my java spring boot application.

Comment: try to explore about cron-parser http://cron-parser.com/
it may help you to solve this

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use cronexpression of quartz to get for next valid fire date of cron.
Ex.

        String orgTimeZone = "US/Eastern";
        String cron = "0 10 2 ? * MON,WED *";
        CronExpression exp = new CronExpression(cron);

        exp.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(orgTimeZone));
        Date date = new Date();
        Date nextValidFireTime = exp.getNextValidTimeAfter(date);
        ZonedDateTime nextExecDate = zonedDateTimeConverter.toZonedDateTime(nextValidFireTime, orgTimeZone);
        ZonedDateTime currentDate = zonedDateTimeConverter.toZonedDateTime(date, orgTimeZone);

        System.out.println(nextExecDate);
        ZonedDateTime after1Hourdate = currentDate.plusHours(1);
        System.out.println(currentDate + ":" + after1Hourdate);
        if (nextExecDate.isAfter(currentDate) && nextExecDate.isBefore(after1Hourdate)) {
            System.out.println("Match Cron");
        }
```